# SQL Server Full-Text-Search FREETEXTTABLE search multiple columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using the below query to return results from a table using Full-Text-Search.
In SQL2000 it was only possible to search one or all columns in a table. Is it possible in SQL 2008?

I would like to search two tables, Problem and Solution (Both indexed and in the same table):

```
DECLARE @topRank int set @topRank=(SELECT MAX(RANK) 
FROM FREETEXTTABLE([Support_Calls], Problem, 'test', 1)) 
SELECT [ID] AS [Call No],Company_Name, Problem, Solution, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST((CAST(ftt.RANK as DECIMAL)/@topRank * 100) AS DECIMAL(13,0))) + '%' as Match 
FROM [Support_Calls] INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE([Support_Calls], Problem, 'test') as ftt ON ftt.[KEY]=[ID] ORDER BY ftt.RANK DESC;
```

From what I can see the FREETEXTTABLE does not accept more than one column?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You specify them in parentheses; `FREETEXTTABLE(tablename, (col1,col2,col3), 'expr')` or use an asterisk to seach all columns in the index.

Comment: Won't the asterisk hurt performance, though, if used without discretion?

Comment: Yes indeed, if there is a column in the index that you don't care about.

Answer (score 1):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx),

*Returns a table of zero, one, or more rows for those columns containing character-based data types for values that match the meaning, but not the exact wording, of the text in the specified freetext_string. FREETEXTTABLE can only be referenced in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement like a regular table name.
Queries using FREETEXTTABLE specify freetext-type full-text queries that return a relevance ranking value (RANK) and full-text key (KEY) for each row.*

They give the following syntax:

```
FREETEXTTABLE (table , { column_name | (column_list) | * } 
          ,'freetext_string' 
     [ , LANGUAGE language_term ] 
     [ ,top_n_by_rank ] )
```

So yes, what Alex K. said as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a FULLTEXT INDEX on different columns, then you can simple use CONTAINS or FREETEXT to look on one of them, all of them, or some of them. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(*, @SearchTerm);

If you want to look on all the columns that are included in the FULLTEXT INDEX. or:

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS((ProductName, ProductNumber, Color), @SearchTerm);
```

If you want to specify the columns that you want to search. If you need the results in one column, you are gonna have to do a UNION and do a search for every column you want to be searched.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(ProductName, @SearchTerm)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(ProductNumber, @SearchTerm)
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS(Color, @SearchTerm)
```

Comment: How would i do if I need only a portion of the word but still will display the full word? Like if the search value is `Curt`, the search result would be `Curtain, Curtis, Curtman...`

Comment: @Rich You would put '"Curt*"' in the `@SearchTerm` - * are wildcards but they must be in double-qoutes and you can only do this with CONTAINS not FREETEXT